# Syntax error before '{' token when declaring a class in cpp standards 

Tags: objective-c

I have declared a header file which is giving Syntax error before '{' token.
I'm using Objective-C++, so the syntax of the header will be in cpp standards.
Below is the header declaration.

```
#import <cocoa/cocoa.h>
#import <curl/curl.h>
class AUHttpConnection
{

  private:

  CURL *m_pHandle;

};
```

I'm not aware of all the things to be taken care while working in Mac, so I have posted this query. Any Options to be used while using Objective-C++?

Comment: i think there's a syntax error in your question title.

Comment: Ya...i too noticed tat after you said......
now is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the extension of the source that include the header file ?
In order to be processed as an [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) source file, you have to use the "mm" extension.

Comment: ya it is mm extension only....
Hey it was silly.....sry for wastin your time....
i was importing my class to which has cpp standards to main.m file...
So i was facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wastin your time....

Mistake was from my part.I was importing header file with cpp standards to main.m file... So i was facing this problem.

Things to be taken care...